# Does the Windows version of Sourcetree not support file renaming?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I watched a tutorial on the Mac version of Sourcetree where right-clicking on a file presented a 'move' option.

However, this option seems absent in my Windows version of Sourcetree.

Is there a known issue with this?

[Windows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nbww.png)

[Mac version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad9hp.png)

If I want to rename a file in the Windows version of Sourcetree, do you have any recommendations?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: In case you're stuck you can call [git mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) on the command line until you have a solution for this. Consider using [sourcetree support](https://support.atlassian.com/sourcetree/) resources and ask people there. Also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Actually, I posed the same question [there](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Does-the-Windows-version-of-Sourcetree-not-support-file-renaming/qaq-p/2463684), but received no response ; ;

Comment: Consider dropping Sourcetree and using the command line exclusively. I became so much more productive when I did that.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with SourceTree 3.4.14 on W11, and the "Move" command is indeed absent from the Windows SourceTree.

That leaves you with the option to define a [custom action](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/using-git-in-custom-actions-785323500.html) calling a Git wrapper script, which would:

- ask for the new name
- call `git mv`